# allow only 5 or less result at a time using jquery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I found this function which display live search result. I am new in jquery and I dont know how I can display only 5 or less live result at a time. here is my function for your reference. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        if(!filter){
            $(".commentlist li").hide();
            return;
        }

        var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");
        // Loop through the comment list
        $(".commentlist li").each(function(){

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) {
                $(this).hide();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });

        // Update the count
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
    });
       });
    });
```

Comment: Please add a js-fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ALso please change `$(window).load(function(){ $(document).ready(function(){` to `(function(){` and remove the last });

Comment: Like said just above, when the window is loaded, document is already ready, so no need to use document ready handler here, or unwrap it from onload handler

Comment: Thanks. I change as as you suggested ::))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More jQuery like would be:

```
    var count = $(".commentlist li").hide().filter(function() {
       return $(this).text().search(regex) >= 0; 
    }).slice(0,5).show().length;
```

Comment: That will stop in the first iteration, as is returning something. You'll prefer to do `if (index === 4) return;`

Comment: No, as far as you call return, your function will stop. http://jsfiddle.net/6K54P/

Comment: @ojovirtual, that's false. The loop will only break if you return false. http://jsfiddle.net/6K54P/1/

Comment: you're right. Forgot to include the index! Shame on me!! ;)

Comment: @DAVE, ive edited it, because my previous answer would not work since did not consider the matched result, so try this. Should work better.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count=0;
$(".commentlist li").each(function(){
    if (count == 5)
        return;
    // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
    if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
    } else {
        $(this).show();
        count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for your ans. It's work when you type any word but if you remove characters one by one it still display more then 5 results??

Comment: Try changing `if(!filter){ $(".commentlist li").hide();return;}`to just `$(".commentlist li").hide();`.

Comment: It's work but if I remove characters one by one search result leave as it is.

Answer (score 1):

you have set counter to `count` variable just check it when you are showing result:

```
$(".commentlist li").each(function(){

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(regex) < 0) {
                $(this).hide();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
               if(count == 4)
               return false; 
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = $(".commentlist li");
    for( var i=0; i < items.length; i++){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if (items.eq(i).text().search(regex) < 0) {
            items.eq(i).hide();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            items.eq(i).show();
            count++;
        }
        if(count == 5){
            break;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this just before the end of your each loop:

```
return ( count !== 5 );
```